Flexibility of compact supports (of continuous functions) on locally compact groups
Imagine a locally compact (hausdorff) group $G$ (remember: in this context local compactness meens that for any point $x \in G$ you find a compact compact neighborhood of $x$).
A continuous function $f:G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be compact supported, if the closure of the set $\{x \in G \mid f(x) \neq 0\}$
($=:$ supp$(f)$, the support$)$ is compact.
Now imagine a continuous (positive) function $f:G \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ of compact support. Is there a continuous function $g:G\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ of compact support, such that $\forall x \in \text{supp}(f):g(x)=1$?
I know: $\forall x\in G \exists U_x \subseteq G, \text{open},K_x \subseteq G, \text{compact}: x \in U_x \subseteq K_x$ hence:
$\text{supp}(f) \subseteq\bigcup_{x \in \text{supp}(f)}U_x$, open cover.
And because of the compactness you get: $\text{supp}(f) \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}U_{x_i}\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}K_{x_i}$ for finitely many $x_i \in \text{supp}(f)$.
So my idea was to construct a function $g$ that is constantly $1$ on supp$(f)$ and goes continuously to zero on $(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}K_{x_i}) \setminus \text{supp}(f)$ in a way that this finite union becomes the support of g (Note that a finite union of compact sets is compact).
I think this exercise is probably easy to see for someone with a little bit of topological background but i am unexperienced in this area of mathematics and currently struggling with bringing this ideas to smooth a solution.
Because:

Why should this new compact set be "bigger" (apart from the case that supp$(f) = G$, because thats trivial)?
Why should it be possible to construct $g$ continuously? I barely have information about the underlying topology.
How can i actually construct $g?$

If there is an other proof, that is easy to see, i would be glad to here it either.

The following version of Urysohn's Lemma gives an easy proof for the existence of a g that meets the required conditions:
Urysohn's Lemma:
Let X be a locally compact hausdorff space, $K \subseteq V \subseteq X$, $V$ open and $K$ compact, than:
$$\exists \phi\in C_c(X): \phi_{\mid K}=1 \wedge \text{supp}(\phi) \subseteq V$$
$C_c(X)$ denotes the compactly supported, continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb C$.
A full proof of this theorem can be found in "Real and Complex Analysis" by W. Rudin p.38 - 40. This book can be found for free download at several link adresses, i will post one below.
Link for the book of Rudin:
https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/real-and-complex-analysis.pdf

Just in case anyone has the same question.

It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

This makes the post harder to find using search and inaccessible to the visually impaired, which is less than ideal.
